# fatal Error Issues - jhotovy's version of android-ffmpeg-x264 - github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg.git

Tags: android, github, ffmpeg

The following is the output for issuing `init-submodules.sh`. I keep receiving this

```
error:fatal error:
    Unable to checkout '15e02184e136e47ecff01bf56aca
    The49d8e2646fb4' in submodule path 'Project/jni/ffmpeg'<br>
```

Has anyone run jhotovy's version of halfninja's code successfully so far? Any help in resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated

My screen output:

```
    gipsyblues@android-general:~/android-ffmpeg$ ./init-submodules.sh <br>
    ls: cannot access ./jni/ffmpeg/*: No such file or directory<br>
    Submodule 'ffmpeg' (git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git) registered for path   Project/jni     /ffmpeg'<br>
    Submodule 'x264' (git://git.videolan.org/x264.git) registered for path 'Project/jni    /x264'<br>
    user.name=xxxxxxx <br>
    user.email=yyyyyyy <br>
    core.repositoryformatversion=0<br>
    core.filemode=true<br>
    core.bare=false<br>
    core.logallrefupdates=true<br>
    remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*<br>
    remote.origin.url=git://github.com/jhotovy/android-ffmpeg.git
    branch.master.remote=origin<br>
    branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master<br>
    submodule.ffmpeg.url=git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git<br>
    submodule.x264.url=git://git.videolan.org/x264.git<br>
    Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni/ffmpeg  /.git/<br>
    remote: Counting objects: 237417, done.<br>
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (57251/57251), done.<br>
    remote: Total 237417 (delta 186957), reused 228690 (delta 179782)<br>
    Receiving objects: 100% (237417/237417), 59.89 MiB | 5.22 MiB/s, done.<br>
    Resolving deltas: 100% (186957/186957), done.<br>
    fatal: reference is not a tree: 15e02184e136e47ecff01bf56aca49d8e2646fb4<br>
    Unable to checkout '15e02184e136e47ecff01bf56aca49d8e2646fb4' in submodule path    'Project/jni/ffmpeg'<br>
   gipsyblues@android-general:~/android-ffmpeg$ <br>
```

I have successfully run the original halfninja version which is also at `githuib.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264.<`br> I have searched all over the Internet and i am not finding any reference to this issue. Anyone had any success with that implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### try this [version](https://github.com/rowntreerob/android-ffmpeg)

i did it again today ( cloned jhotovy android-ffmpeg ) and ffmpeg submodule was not included in the pull for init_submodule.sh.

go to the orig project on git to get the 'ffmpeg' directory ( see halfninja ) and drop everything else , merging 'ffmpeg' into the jhotovy file structure.

that should work ok

--build details--

- make sure that your build env is good for cross toolchains being
  employed ( NDK/ ant / android SDK )
- make sure that u have synched your NDK to the appropriate ENV vars in the build scripts in the jni directory
- clone 'hotovy' for the additions ogg/vorbis/theora
- clone 'halfninja' to get the aborted 'ffmpeg' submodule no longer handled
  by above
- merge ./Project/jni/ffmpeg from 'halfninja' into 'hotovy' version of ./Proj/jni/ffmpeg
- cd to 'hotovy' ./Proj/jni and run 'config_make_everything.sh'
- check output from above, stay in jni dir
- and run ' $NDK/ndk-build V=1 -B' checking output

You should now have good native libs for 'ffmpeg' and for 'videokit'  in .Project/libs/arm directory.

To get the .apk , i would hook up ant/android to the project by issuing an 'update' command like

```
android create project -n ffmpegtst -t 1 -p ffmpegtst -k com.b2bpo.media.ffmpeg.test -a RecordActivity
```

you will have to read about managing projects from the commandline in developer.android.

when u get ant hooked up, cd to Project directory and run

ant debug

u should get the apk in ./Project/bin directory

Comment: rowntreerob, what I need help with is the portion of your response saying " To get the .apk hook up ant/android..... how do you hookup android and ant? 2. I have read the managing projects from the commandline in developer.android. Do I need to create any special files in addition to the files already provided. What do i need to do and in which directory? Could please clarify the command you gave above substituting Project, ProjectTest, and the appropriate activity? That should be of tremendous help to me. TIA

Comment: Thanks Robert, will take a look at your solution. Cheers

Comment: rowntreerob, I am having problems running your version of the android-ffmpeg.  I am receiving a lot of errors at ./configure_make_everything.sh. I seem to be missing several make files. Also could you please confirm what version of NDK you used? BTW your instruction set does not include./create_toolchains.sh.

Comment: i used my own toolchain. i think if u look into ./jni/settings.sh you can see that im using a toolchain. You have to be far enough into this stuff so that you know how to integrate a toolchain. Also, you can look at ./configure_make_all and run those inner scripts one at a time. Example cd to ffmpeg , run ./jni/settings.sh then run configure_ffmpeg and then look at the errors in 'config.log' in ffmpeg dir.

Comment: i used ndk-r8b on ubuntu for the builds. without seeing the config.log in ffmpeg dir , i have no idea what the problem is

Comment: rowntreerob, I went back and repeated the whole process  thsi time following the setup instructions one the first and previous pages. I am able to build the ffmpeg. However ndk-build gives me the following error:

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `jasongipsyblues@android-master:~/android-ffmpeg/Project/jni$ ndk-build
Executable     : ffmpeg
/home/jasongipsyblues/Desktop/apps/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: cannot find -landroid
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/jasongipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/ffmpeg] Error 1`

Comment: OK.. its a linker error related to following in Android.mk >>>LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz -landroid $(FFMPEG_LIBS) x264/libx264.a<<< Can not find the 'android' lib... in my toolchain, i have the following... >>>toolchain-android14/sysroot/usr/lib/libandroid.so
<<<  YOU DO NOT HAVE YOUR TOOLCHAIN HOOKED UP CORRECTLY!

Comment: look at settings.sh in ./Project/jni and get all the NDK stuff integrated... NDK_BASE, NDK_SYSROOT ... echo stmts in the shell script should help you verify that all the vars point to dirs / files that exists. when that is correct then $NDK/build-ndk should work.

Comment: @rowntreerob, how does one paste a file of a size larger than the total characters allowed by these comment boxes. My config.log file for the ffmpeg build is really huge. The above box contains the ndk-build error and not the config.log. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: i put the result of $NDK/ndk-build V=1 -B on a pastebin... http://pastebin.com/y04cmXBM

Comment: @rowntreerob, please check this link:     [link] http://pastebin.com/7cT6NfgE for my edited copy of the settings.sh file I downloaded from your android-ffmpeg git. I eventually hard-coded the path to the linker and I am still getting the same error.    I have pasted the ndk-build output at this link     [link]http://pastebin.com/HG2Pe7cy. I do not seem to have any issues creating the ffmpeg binary. But it looks like I am missing something very fundamental. Any extra help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rowntreerob, sorry for bothering you. I fixed the tools.jar file not found issue. I re-installed the openjdk6 and made sure that jre does not over write jdk. However I still have 2 issues left for the last step of 'ant debug" What is the correct format for the version-tag line in the build.xml file.[link](http://pastebin.com/CHGH0App). One is supposed to replace the integer 1 by custom. 2 I am also receiving a _italic_ **bold** 'no regular expression matcher found. Please see [link](http://pastebin.com/nykPB9L0) for full expression. My heartiest thanks to you for all the time you have spent

Comment: if u have issues with build.xml , just cd to parent of /Project and do an "android update project... " That should fix any issues with the build file. You normally DO NOT touch the build.xml . As it says, the SDK creates that file for you.

Answer (score 0):

that project worked for me.

all i remember doing was:

git clone

read README in

cd into root/Project/jni and reading INSTALL there.

Comment: rowntreerob, thanks for your suggestions.<br/> Could you please confirm how you built the final apk after successfully creating the ffmpeg and videokit shared objects. <br/>As you are aware the project is based on ant.I have no clue as to the steps involved in proceeding from the point of successfully building the first part.<br/><br/> I am used to just using Eclipse to import a project file then using export to get my final apk. Any tips will be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: what exactly do u need?

ffmpeg + x264 + android CLI interface to ffmpeg ( no java , no apk )
--OR--
ffmpeg + x264 + vorbis + theora + ogg + java wrappers and .apk via ant --OR--

ffmpeg + full WebM + java + apk

Option 2 above is IMO good reason to select 'hotovy' from git. There are alot of git clones (descendants of halfninja maybe) on ffmpeg and depending on EXACTLY WHAT you want to do, u would gravitate to one or the other forks of ffmpeg. 

ill put up another full-detl answer to option #2 , how to build it with ant and get both the cli interface and the .apk wrappers

Comment: Once again thanks for going out of your way to help. What I am looking for is OPTION 2. I am able to build the library objects, ffmpeg and the videokit shared object. After that no clue

Comment: added comments to my orig answer

Comment: Thanks Robert. Will review your suggestion. Cheers

Comment: rowntreerob, I tried to build your version of the android-ffmpeg and I am getting a lot of errors and eventually failed to build the app. Considering the fact that I have successfuly built the halfninja, and andy versions, i think it is the instructions you gave which may not be clear to me. Could you please answer the folloiwng:

Comment: --sysroot ?? your search chains in lines ( 8, 10) do not agree with sysroot.. you have a platform conflict 3 or 14??

Comment: @rowntreerob, before coming back to this page, I decided to print out your ndk-build output and compared that to mine. the value of android level in the project.properties  file was set to 3 not to 16 as in yours. By changing it to 16, your solution was created smoothly!. We are lucky to have guys like you around here!. Your above comments DEAD ON! Final question: if i were to build this solution for an android 2.3.3 (android-10) level which are the parameters I need to change and in what files? Thanks a lot!

Comment: good luck on 2.3.3 and the slower hardware/ diff CPU's ... glad that it worked out for u. dont forget about giving credit to those who help.

Comment: @rowntreerob, Final steps. Could you please help interpret this error I receive for ant debug.    _italic_ **bold** ` jasongipsyblues@android-master:~/android-ffmpeg/Project$ ant debug
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/jasongipsyblues/android-ffmpeg/Project/build.xml:89: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName. 

Total time: 0 seconds
jasongipsyblues@android-master:~/android-ffmpeg/Project$  `. I have my build.xml file here

Comment: @rowntreerob: it appears I spoke too soon. Please ignore my last entry, I am still getting used to this environment- especially hitting the enter button. With the final step: ant debug, I got this error: [link](http://pastebin.com/HN3Y2jmV) This is my build.xml file. [link](http://pastebin.com/CHGH0App)  Could you please confirm where I am messing up. I have set the correct ndk and sdk directories in the local.properties file. With regards to credit would you mind if i submitted for your consideration  an updated readme file for your git version by re-arranging the sequence of execution. TIA.

Comment: @rowntreerob, I missed this earlier - re hardware and android version, my base hardware is the Cortex A8 running at 1.2 GHz with the Mali400 GPU. I tend to use Android 2.3.3 as my base test platform.TIA